# Lower bounds on regret

Tags: optimization, online-algorithms

In "regret" styled analysis over $T$ steps of an iterative algorithm $\{x_i \in F \}_{i=1}^T$ (where $F$ is some feasible set) being given the sequence of loss functions $\{ f_i\}_{i=1}^T$ one defines the regret $R_T = \sum_{i=1}^Tf_t(x_i) - \min_{x \in F} \sum_{i=1}^T f_t(x)$ Most typical analyses assume that the $f$s are convex.

Is this notion of "regret" lower bounded? 
Or under what conditions is it lower bounded?

I guess "minimizing the regret" does not make sense because one can always have an "Oracle" access to the sequence of points $x^*_i$ such that $x^*_i = \min_{x \in F} f_i(x)$. Then for this sequence for $x^*$ points the regret is only at most $0$.

Comment: There are lower bounds on regret that show that the classical algorithms cannot be improved. The lower bounds give an adversary which can force *any* algorithm to have a certain amount of regret.

Comment: Thanks! Can you kindly link to the reference? And this lower bound is $0$?

Comment: The lower bound is certainly not 0. There are better lower bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different models in which regret minimization makes sense. One particular model is Gaussian density estimation. Takimoto and Warmuth, in their paper [The minimax strategy for Gaussian density estimation](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~manfred/pubs/C56.pdf), give a tight analysis which includes both an upper bound achieved by a particular algorithm and an almost matching lower bound proved using the adversary method. There are probably many more such analyses out there.

Comment: Thanks! So in general I know of papers which in the context of such algorithms try to prove that the average regret i.e $\frac{R_T}{T}$is asymptotically $0$. What could be the motivation of trying to prove this particular limit? (...given that what the lower bound is seems to depend on the model and the distribution and other things as you say..)

Comment: This lower bound matches the performance of the proposed algorithm. Stated differently, the lower bound shows that the regret guaranteed by the algorithm is optimal.

Comment: While it's true that the average regret goes to zero, we are still interested in *how fast* it decays.

Comment: But what about my "oracle" based argument that $R_T$ can always be made at most $0$? If that is correct then why is average regret asymptotically going to $0$ (no matter how fats) even a good thing? Shouldnt one be targetting to get regret as negative? (because that is clearly possible for the oracle)

Comment: You cannot get negative regret. In the formula for regret, you're comparing the performance of your algorithm with the performance of the optimal after-the-fact algorithm. You cannot beat the optimal choice!

Comment: No! Thats the catch I see : what is "optimal" point here (say $x^*$) is w.r.t to the sum. But for each $f_t$ its always possible to find a $x^*_t$ such that $f_t(x^*_t) \leq f_t(x^*)$. What stops this?

Comment: The catch is that we do want to use the same point $x^*$ for all $f_t$'s. Think of it as choosing the best weather reporter – you want to compare yourself to the best reporter, not to the best report on every single day. This is the usual scenario in regret minimization. There could be other scenarios in which your standard of comparison does make sense.

Comment: Or consider the "mixture of experts" scenario – in the end you want to end up with a single expert, which is what you will use as your future classifier. If you could choose the expert based on the sample, that would amount to cheating.

Comment: But $\{ x_t \}_{t=1,..,T}$ is the sequence of steps the algorithm takes. The regret as defined is a function of the algorthm's history and not just the final answer it returns.  If somehow the algorithm knows the $f_t$ before having to decide on $x_t$ then could have very well chosen $x_t = min_{x \in F} f_t(x)$ and then land up with a negative regret. The only thing preventing this is the fact that the algorithm doesnt know $f_t$ when it has to decide on $x_t$. So there is a difficulty for the algorithm to get negative regret but as a function $R_T$ can be negative.

Comment: If the algorithm knows $f_t$ when it has to decide on $x_t$, there is no need to use a regret minimization algorithm. Just choose the best $x_t$.

Comment: Summarizing, negative regret is theoretically possible, but in traditional settings, there is an adversary that can force the regret to be positive.